# Getting error from Zookeeper Unexpected exception causing shutdown while sock still open java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

Sometimes, with no reason, I'm getting this error in my logs:

```
2017-05-18 19:19:17,206 [] - ERROR [] - Unexpected exception causing shutdown while sock still open
        java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
        at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readInt(BinaryInputArchive.java:63)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPacket.deserialize(QuorumPacket.java:83)
        at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readRecord(BinaryInputArchive.java:103)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.LearnerHandler.run(LearnerHandler.java:546)
```

Besides this info in log I see no effect of that. Any of our clients are not complaining about loosing connection to ZK or whatever. What can be cause of this error log?

Zookeeper version: **3.4.6**
Curator version: **2.6.0**

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue also. It's a reported bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-3036

Looks like the only fix is to restart the node.